# ¿Como funcionan las FormAction?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

No entiendo el como hace el slotmapping para poder saber que "utterance" contestar al usuario para poder obtener el "entity" pedido.
ejemplo de mi clase form:

```
class RestaurantForm(FormAction):
  """Example of a custom form action"""
  def name(self):
    # type: () -> Text
    """Unique identifier of the form"""
    return "formaejemplo"

  @staticmethod
  def required_slots(tracker):
    # type: () -> List[Text]
    """A list of required slots that the form has to fill"""
    return ["valor1","valor2","valor3"]

  def slot_mappings(self):
    return {"valor1": self.from_entity(entity="valor1",intent="getvalor1"),
                "valor2": self.from_entity(entity="valor2",intent="getvalor2"),
                "valor3": self.from_entity(entity="valor3",intent="getvalor3")}

  def submit(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
    dispatcher.utter_template('utter_listo', tracker)
    return []
```

domain.yml:

```
intents: 
- peticion_habitacion:
    use_entities: false
- getvalor1
- getvalor2
- getvalor3

entities:
- valor1
- valor2
- valor3

slots:
  valor1:
    type: unfeaturized
    auto_fill: false
  valor2:
    type: unfeaturized
    auto_fill: false
  valor3:
    type: unfeaturized
    auto_fill: false

actions:
- utter_prueba
- utter_completo

templates:
  utter_completo:
  - text: "listo:\nvalor 1 {valor1} \nvalor 2 {valor2} \nvalor 3 {valor3}"

  utter_prueba:
  - text: "iniciando prueba:\n"  

  utter_valor1:
  - text: "dame el valor 1 no enteros"

  utter_valor2:
  - text: "dame el valor 2 no enteros" 

  utter_valor3:
  - text: "dame el valor 3 no enteros"  

  utter_listo:
  - text: "prueba completa"  

forms:
 - formaejemplo
```

en la sección donde obtiene el valor1,valor2 etc...
esta según la documentación de Rasa:
`"valor1": self.from_entity(entity="valor1",intent="getvalor1"`
"el valor 1 sera obtenido del `intent getvalor1`."

mi duda es, en que momento o en que parte o que archivo, se le dice a la action form que tendrá que mandar el "utterance" "utter_valor1" o "utter_valor2", porque a varios ejemplos de Internet mas los mismos ejemplos de bots de rasa, veo que estos mandan los utterance y luego recuperan el valor, mas yo no logro conseguir entender el como mandan el utterance y luego obtienen el valor

Comment: ¿que significan las etiquetas `rasa-nlu` y `rasa-core`?

Comment: significan que estoy trabajando con rasa-nlu y rasa-core, unas herramientas para la creación de chatbots, espero y te sirva